# python class static method dynamic binding static data member

Tags: python, static-methods, static-members

I really don't know how to describe this problem good enough. So i think an example is more expressive:

```
class A:
    c=1
    @staticmethod
    def b(): return A.c

class B(A):
    c=2
```

I hope `B.b()` returns `2`. but the reality is it does not. in which way am i gonna achieve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to access a class attribute, why are you using a staticmethod instead of a classmethod?

Comment: oh jesus. i must have a gunshot in my brain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod), and hardcoding the class `A`, instead of using a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), and using the `cls` argument.

Try this:

```
class A:
    c=1
    @classmethod
    def b(cls): return cls.c
```

The docs (linked above) explain the difference, but you may want to try looking at Stack Overflow questions like [What is the difference between `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) for a more in-depth discussion. Briefly: a `staticmethod` is basically just a global function inside the class's namespace, while a `classmethod` is a method on the class object; if you want to use any class attributes (or the class itself, as in the alternate constructor idiom), you want the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use a class method, so you could reference the class dynamically.  A static method like you are currently using is not bound to any class, so you have to statically explicitly reference the `A` class as you are.

```
class A(object):
    c = 1
    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        return cls.c

class B(A):
    c = 2
```